# How to Convert an array into json which contains double quote in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I want to convert an array into JSON. My problem is that one of that elements in that array contain single quotes, double quotes etc.

```
<textarea name="description" id="description">
   Tesla is the living definition of bad*** and mad scientist. 
   During Tesla's later years, he made claims concerning a 
   "teleforce" weapon after studying the Van de Graaff generator. 
   The press called it a "peace ray" or death ray. Tesla described 
   the weapon as being able to be used against ground-based infantry 
   or for antiaircraft purposes.
</textarea>
```

When I submit it I got:

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
json_encode($description);
```

When I decode it, I got only a part of string.

Comment: where are the complete codes?

Comment: addslashes() http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php wrapping it around you $description should fix the issue.

Comment: ok when I save this value using addslashes() and retive back from database , will slashes apper ?

Comment: When you decode it, you only get part of the string; but does the full string exist encoded or is only a portion being encoded?

Comment: not reproducable ([here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CACnT2))

Comment: @user3054209 you will have to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php when you spit it back out. You really should not be saving json to a database it is asking for a mess.

Comment: it broke "Tesla is the living definition of badass and mad scientist. During Teslas later years, he made claims concerning a "

Comment: mean just before the first double quote

Comment: `json_encode($description);` --- do you realize that this expression does not modify anything?

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you could try with [addcslashes](https://www.php.net/addcslashes), which is more adapted (you can define a list of parameters to escape).

Comment: ok when I save this value using addslashes() and retive back from database , will slashes apper ? –

Comment: Of course they will, but you should be able to remove them afterwards with [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripslashes.php) (or stripcslashes in that case). But why do you want to save JSON in a database ?

Comment: I want to save them in a cookie, it will use after 15 mins when user fills lot of forms. then from cookies i will take those values and save in database